# Error while importing to repository from Azure sql database

Tags: mysql, logging

We have taken the export backup of DBA_REP (database-1) and importing to cust1_rep (database-2) i.e customer repository, while importing into cust1_rep, we are getting below error.

When we are checking line no 126, its showing ENGINE=MyISAM */. Instead of INNODB.

[root@MTC-ZURICH-TOMCAT1 MySql_dumps]# cat imp_dba_rep.log
ERROR 1030 (HY000) at line 126: Got error 1 from storage engine

Comment: Does this link helps you [here](https://azuresqlblog.azurewebsites.net/api/BlogRedirect?PostURL=/2017/06/08/azure-database-for-mysql-cant-restore-database-with-error-got-error-1-from-storage-engine/)